# OpenGL shader cant bind attribute

Tags: opengl-es, attributes, glsl

i've got three glsl attributes in my vertex shader

```
attribute highp   vec4  Position;
attribute mediump vec4  UV;
attribute mediump vec3  Normal;
```

that im binding using

```
glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "Position");
glBindAttribLocation(program, 1, "Normal");
glBindAttribLocation(program, 2, "UV");
```

However, i'm getting an error

*Could not find vertex shader attribute 'Normal' to match BindAttributeLocation request.*

Why can it find the Position and UV attributes but not the Normal attribute.

Any help would be highly appreciated as i'm pretty confused.

Cheers

Edit:
I have the same issue on Android OpenGLES20. 
I'll add sample code : the rest of the class is the official GLSurfaceView tutorial

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {

    String mVertexShader =  "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n " +
            "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n " +
            "attribute vec4 aNormal; \n " + //this is the line I added
            "attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;\n " +
            "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n " +
            "void main() {\n " +
            "gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
            "  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;\n" +
            "}\n";

    mProgram = createProgram(mVertexShader, mFragmentShader); // cf tutorial
    if (mProgram == 0) {
        return;
    }
    initShaderHandles(); //initializes the rest of the handles (cf tutorial)

     // my little additional code
    int maNormalHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aNormal");
    Log.d("ATTRIB LOCATION Normal: ", maNormalHandle + "");
    checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation normal");
    if (maNormalHandle == -1) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Could not get attrib location for normal");
    }
    // ...and we crash.

}
```

Comment: I should add that i've tested the shader to make sure the modifications are working correctly, but still cant bind the Normal attribute

Comment: Where do you get this error from?

Comment: I should point out that I have the exact same problem "sometimes" on Android OpenGLES20. Take the tutorial, add a "normal", "aNormal", "norm", "whatever" to the sample shader code, try to bind it right after and it crashes.

Comment: @Thomas Have you just added in your "me too" comment into another user's question? This can get quite confusing.

Comment: yup, sorry, my bad - it's just that I realized I had the sample code that someone might need to reply to this question. Only then I understood Rickard's answer. I understand how confusing it's become. Sorry again!

Answer (score 15):

Are you using the normal in the shader or else it can be optimized out by the glsl-compiler. If it is something else please show us your shaders

Comment: for what it's worth this is the correct answer to the android issue that I mentioned. Thanks Rickard.

Comment: This seems the obvious, and to be accepted, answer, as the attribute is not used in the shader and optimizing inactive attibutes/uniforms away is quite common behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are passing the correct index to the shader?
You could try getting the index by calling

```
glGetAttribLocation(program,"Normal");
```

Comment: You can pass whatever index you want *before* linking. Or you can ask for an (auto-assigned) index *after* linking. There is no "correct index".